# CPOI and CWaypoint

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have used operator overloading for +=operator like this

```
CRoute& CRoute::operator+=(string name ){
CWaypoint *p=this->m_pWpDatabase->getPointerToWp(name);
if(p!=NULL){
this->addWaypoint(name);
}
else{
cout<<" Waypoint not found in DB "<<endl;
}
return *this;
}
```

Now i want to do same operation += to add poi to my route,i am using the syntax
CRoute& operator+=(string namepoi);

but i am getting error message as 'CRoute& CRoute::operator+=(std::string)' cannot be overloaded
Can someone help??

Answer (score 1):

Function signature of your suggested operator overloaded function is conflicting with the one existing currently.   So if you would like to create operator overloading for `poi`  why can't you pass the `poi object` instead  its name?